# Converting from integer to binary and back in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've been banging my head against the wall with this one all morning.

The following SQL code and its' result makes no sense to me:

```
select CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(BINARY(30),2691485888))
```

which results in:

```
-1060082528
```

What?  Why doesn't the result equal my original integer?

My whole objective is to convert an integer into bytes and store those bytes into the database, but without getting this basic example to work I am stuck.  Can anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

By the way, I am using Sql Server 2005 (9.0.4340)

Comment: Can you explain why you need to convert the integer into bytes? Why can't you store it in an INT column?

Comment: @kekekela - If the reasoning behind this is known, an better alternative might be the answer. Context is important.

Comment: For one thing, 2,691,485,888 is larger than what an `INT` can hold.

Comment: Use unsigned int instead of int ;p

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As I noted in my earlier comment, 2,691,485,888 is larger than what an INT can hold.

This will work:

```
select CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(BINARY(30), CONVERT(BIGINT, 2691485888)))
```

Comment: Ah! This makes sense. I always was at a loss as to why I was unable to cast, say, 5B to binary, but it was because it was implicitly casting 5B to int before the explicit cast to binary. Thanks much.

Comment: Yep the implicit cast was what I was missing too.

Comment: You can also just make it unsigned to keep it a normal 4 byte int

Answer (score 4):

The value `2691485888` cannot be held in an [INT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187745.aspx) - it is too large:

> int -2^31 (-2,147,483,648) to 2^31-1 (2,147,483,647) 4 Bytes

There is a good chance you are seeing the result of an overflow.

A data type that can handle that value is BIGINT.

Comment: That makes sense; but is there any way to get around it?

Answer (score 1):

2691485888 is beyond the upper-bound of the integer datatype (which is 2147483647)

If you convert it to bigint, it should result in the correct amount.

Comment: but select CONVERT(BIGINT, CONVERT(BINARY(30),2691485888)) returns 720575947909131424 which is also incorrect...

Comment: @Slider345: The reason you get an unexpected answer is because SQL Server interprets the literal value 2691485888 to have type DECIMAL(10,0). The conversion to binary(30) and then to bigint will only get you back where you started if you started with a bigint. Note that this gives you the result 2691485888: SELECT CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,0), CONVERT(BINARY(30), 2691485888))